# How to Display data in textblock after JSON Parsing

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to parse some json data in my Windows application. I had written some codes for the same. The code is error free but no data appears in my textblock. Here is my XAML

```
<TextBlock Name="acc1" Margin="180, 60, 0, 0"   Text="{Binding Accnumber1}" Foreground="White"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" />
                                <TextBlock Name="bal1" Margin="180, 90,0, 0"    Text="{Binding Availablebalance}" Foreground="White"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" />
                                <TextBlock Name="acc2" Margin="180, 140, 0, 0"  Text="{Binding Accnumber2}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" />
                                <TextBlock Name="bal2" Margin="180, 170, 0, 0"  Text="{Binding Availablebalance}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="22" />
```

and this my class file

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckForAnimation();
        BackKeyPress += OnBackKeyPressed;

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
        ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://mobimybank.appspot.com/loginresponse.json"));
    }



    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
            {
                var root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
                  this.DataContext = root1;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ProgressBarRequest.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }
```

This is the RootObject class file

```
public class Mybank
{
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Accnumber1 { get; set; }
    public string Availablebalance { get; set; }
    public string Accnumber2 { get; set; }
}

public class Accounts
{
    public List<Account> Account { get; set; }
}

public class Loginresponse
{
    public Mybank { get; set; }
    public Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Loginresponse loginresponse { get; set; }
}
```

When i added a watcher at data context it tells me the data is been fetched. But the data is not displayed in above given textblocks.
please tell me the area i am doing things wrong or the correct method to display the data.

Comment: I would use DependencyProperties: Text ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ClassReferingTo}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Brand_Name}" ..... your code behind: create a dependency object (Brand_Name) to refer to. You should deal with depProps ... google it :)

Comment: You have bound TextBloxks to properties Brand, Type. But when you change ObservableCollection the event is raised with property Results.

Comment: firstly thanks for responding, i would request you to please brief a little more so that i can exactly understand my mistake.

Comment: what are you getting in results ? are you getting the list? if yes the where are you assigning the contents on textblock?

Comment: The textblock fields are empty. I am assigning the content in my textblock - txt 7/8/9/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for the same, the declaration will be like this for a single text block

```
this.txt1.DataContext= root1.loginresponse.Accounts.Account;
```

Answer (score 0):

The json that you are trying to parse contains an array of RootObject. Hence you should be using a ListBox in XAML, like this:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="list">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

During parsing you should use an array type, and set the list's ItemsSource property to it, like this:

```
RootObject[] results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);
list.ItemsSource = results;
```

Hope this helps. Mark as answer if it works out for you.

Comment: @DeepeshDoshi The JSON parsing is working properly. I think now the problem is with data binding. Since you are getting an array of RootObject, you should use a ListBox. I have modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Error: 
list - list.itemsource = results; 

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

what does this error means ??

Comment: @DeepeshDoshi It simply requires that your results variable should be static. Declare it as static outside function definition, like
`static RootObject[] results;`